# Kitchen faucet screw hole leaks water?

Tags: leak, faucet, hole

My kitchen faucet has a hole in the side (see picture) which appears to have a screw slot. It leaks a lot of water. Why is it there? How can I stop it from leaking?

[image: Kitchen faucet with hole]

Comment: It's probably a release for the handle. While I'm generally in favor of repair before replace, this faucet has seen better days. It might not be worth the effort.

Comment: looking at the surface finish, the corrosion at the joint, and the info about the leaking mystery screw, i think it might be time to get out the explosives and get a new faucet.

Comment: Thanks. Looks better in real life, but probably it's ready to go.